# Nestjs Swagger css not loading when deployed to vercel

Tags: node.js, swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

Nestjs swagger ui not loading styles when deployed to vercel but works well locally

[image]

console and network requests
[image]

[image]

I added vercel.json with the following configuration and deployed to vercel.

```js
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "src/main.ts",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "src/main.ts",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE"]
    }
  ]
}
```

main.ts

```js
const swaggerConfig = new DocumentBuilder()
  .setTitle('Tansfun')
  .setDescription('API for Tansfun')
  .setVersion('1.0')

  .addBearerAuth(
    {
      type: 'http',
      scheme: 'bearer',
      bearerFormat: 'APIKey',
      name: 'APIKey',
      description: 'Enter API Key',
      in: 'header',
    },
    'APIKey-auth', 
  )
  .build();

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, swaggerConfig);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());

  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);

  await app.listen(port);
}
bootstrap();
```

I used @nestjs/swagger v6

Comment: Can you add screenshots of the Network and Console tabs from your browser dev tools? So we can see what the exact errors are.

Comment: @Helen I have added the screenshots for the console and Network

Comment: @Rickhomes Hi..? Did u find a solution for this issue..? I am facing the same issue as u.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently came across this issue.
Fortunately I found a working working solution
The solution is a bit hacky tho

## The First Solution

Is to get you api's **swagger JSON file** host it and use it with a **swagger ui explorer**

- Serve your **swagger JSON file** statically with nestjs
- Get the path to the **swagger JSON file** on your vercel server
- Use it with a **swagger ui explorer**

### How To Achieve Solution 1

#### Steps

- On your local machine / development machine set the `NODE_ENV` variable to **development**.

In your **.env file**

```
NODE_ENV="development"
```

- Create a static folder in your projects root. eg: **swagger-static**
- Statically serve content of the swagger-static folder
  here is link to documentation on [serving static files with nestjs](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static)

In your `app.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join } from 'path';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'swagger-static'),
      serveRoot: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '/' : '/swagger',
    }),
   ],
   controllers: [AppController],
   providers: [AppService],
 })

export class AppModule {}
```

- Every time your app starts in development you then to generate your api
  s swagger json and store in a `swagger.json` file in the **swagger-static folder** in your prjects root directory

This [issue on github](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/110) discusses and has a solution on how to generate a **swagger JSON file** for your api

Below is a code snippet on how to generate the `swagger.json` file

In your `main.ts`

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { SwaggerModule, DocumentBuilder } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { writeFileSync } from 'fs';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Cats example')
    .setDescription('The cats API description')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addTag('cats')
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('/swagger', app, document);

  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

  // get the swagger json file (if app is running in development mode)
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    const pathToSwaggerStaticFolder = resolve(process.cwd(), 'swagger-static');

    // write swagger json file
    const pathToSwaggerJson = resolve(
      pathToSwaggerStaticFolder,
      'swagger.json',
    );
    const swaggerJson = JSON.stringify(document, null, 2);
    writeFileSync(pathToSwaggerJson, swaggerJson);
    console.log(`Swagger JSON file written to: '/swagger-static/swagger.json'`);
  }
}

bootstrap();
```

- Now every time your app starts in **development** the **swagger JSON file** with the generated
- In **production** it would be served on your vercel domain eg: `https://yourprojectname.vercel.app/swagger/swagger.json`
- Push you changes to vercel and test your swagger api by using the path to the swagger.json file on your server
- Eg: Head to the swagger ui explorer page https://petstore.swagger.io/?_ga=2.160760958.2144886769.1670328433-858019792.1670328433#/. On the the page enter the path to your `swagger.json` file in the explorer input and click explore. Your swagger docs your now be loaded

## The Second Solution (recommend)

Is to get missing swagger files in development and manually serve them statically on vercel (your production serve)

### How To Achieve Solution 2

#### Steps

- On your local machine / development machine set the `NODE_ENV` variable to **development**.

In your **.env file**

```
NODE_ENV="development"
```

- Create a static folder in your projects root. eg: **swagger-static**
- Statically serve content of the swagger-static folder
  here is link to documentation on [serving static files with nestjs](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static)

In your `app.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join } from 'path';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'swagger-static'),
      serveRoot: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '/' : '/swagger',
    }),
   ],
   controllers: [AppController],
   providers: [AppService],
 })

export class AppModule {}
```

- Every time your app starts in development you make and http call to fetch the missing swagger ui resources on your production server.
  In my case the missing files were `swagger-ui-bundle.js`, `swagger-ui-init.js`, `swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js` and `swagger-ui.css`
- In your main.ts file after your app has started check if your app is in development an fetch the missing swagger resources then store them in the **swagger-static folder** in your root directory

  ```
   import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
   import { SwaggerModule, DocumentBuilder } from '@nestjs/swagger';
   import { AppModule } from './app.module';
   // core
   import { resolve } from 'path';
   import { writeFileSync, createWriteStream } from 'fs';
   import { get } from 'http';

   async function bootstrap() {
     const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

     const options = new DocumentBuilder()
       .setTitle('Cats example')
       .setDescription('The cats API description')
       .setVersion('1.0')
       .addTag('cats')
       .build();
     const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
     SwaggerModule.setup('/swagger', app, document);

     await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

     // get the swagger json file (if app is running in development mode)
     if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {

       // write swagger ui files
       get(
         `${serverUrl}/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js`, function 
         (response) {
           response.pipe(createWriteStream('swagger-static/swagger-ui-bundle.js'));
           console.log(
       `Swagger UI bundle file written to: '/swagger-static/swagger-ui-bundle.js'`,
     );
       });

       get(`${serverUrl}/swagger/swagger-ui-init.js`, function (response) {
         response.pipe(createWriteStream('swagger-static/swagger-ui-init.js'));
         console.log(
       `Swagger UI init file written to: '/swagger-static/swagger-ui-init.js'`,
     );
       });

       get(
     `${serverUrl}/swagger/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js`,
     function (response) {
         response.pipe(
         createWriteStream('swagger-static/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js'),
       );
         console.log(
         `Swagger UI standalone preset file written to: '/swagger-static/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js'`,
       );
       });

       get(`${serverUrl}/swagger/swagger-ui.css`, function (response) {
         response.pipe(createWriteStream('swagger-static/swagger-ui.css'));
         console.log(
       `Swagger UI css file written to: '/swagger-static/swagger-ui.css'`,
     );
       });

     }
   }

   bootstrap();
  ```
- Now every time your app starts in development the missing swagger would be fetched localy and stored in the **swagger-static folder**
- In production file missing would be served upon request on your vercel server
- Push you changes to vercel and test your swagger. Everything should be working now

Comment: I have to include a get request to `index.html` to get it working on vercel.

Answer (score 9):

try with this, set the custom js and css

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  // swagger setup
  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Backend Generator')
    .setDescription('Documentation API Test')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .setBasePath('api/v1')
    .addBearerAuth({ type: 'http', scheme: 'bearer', bearerFormat: 'JWT' })
    .build();

  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('swagger', app, document, {
    customSiteTitle: 'Backend Generator',
    customfavIcon: 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/6936373?s=200&v=4',
    customJs: [
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/4.15.5/swagger-ui-bundle.min.js',
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/4.15.5/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.min.js',
    ],
    customCssUrl: [
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/4.15.5/swagger-ui.min.css',
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/4.15.5/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.min.css',
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/4.15.5/swagger-ui.css',
    ],
  });
  const cors = { ...CorsConfig };
  app.enableCors(cors);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true }));
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api/v1');
  useContainer(app.select(AppModule), { fallbackOnErrors: true });

  await app.listen(5000);
}
bootstrap();
```